# Google Analytics GA4 Content Group

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

I have ga4 google analytics on my website running and the realtime reporting is great

I will like to have a new report using "content group" for grouping website pages (+3000) in 20 or 30 basic topics

I tried to follow https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11523339?hl=en
and added

```
gtag('set', 'content_group', 'ZZZ');
```

in my GA4 script after

```
gtag('config', 'G-nnnnn' );
```

with ZZZ changing according on each webpage. ZZZ can took around 30 different values

48 hs later,  although not seen any error in chrome console,
if I go to google analytics -> "Pages and screens: Page title and screen class" report
and filter the 1st column by "content group"
I only get a blank line and not the ZZZ values

what I'm missing ?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is just wrong for GA4. You cannot use `set` to set `content_group` with GA4 like you can with UA. Rather, `content_group` must be set with the `config` call, like this:

```js
gtag('config', 'G-nnnnn', {'content_group': 'ZZZ'});
```

or alternatively, with individual events:

```js
gtag('event', 'event_name', {
    'content_group': 'ZZZ',
    // other event data
});
```

The latter can also be used in combination with the former to override the page-wide content group for a single event.

Additionally unlike UA where you could set multiple content groups with `content_group1`, `content_group2`, ..., etc. GA4 only supports the one content group.